# Specifying run-time packages list in Delphi Tokyo

Tags: delphi

I would like to use **link with run-time packages** to build my `App.exe`.

My question is that what's the different between leaving the run-time packages list empty or specifying some run-time packages into the list.

#### Empty

[image]

#### Specifying some packages

[image]

> As the result of both approaches I still have to deploy `rtl250.bpl` and `vcl250.bpl` anyway to result my `App.exe` be able to run.

**Question** So what is the different ?

Comment: Without runtime packages (the list is empty), the packages are included inside the exe so you won't need to deploy them in that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These packages are probably already mentioned in the inherited configurations. Thus it makes no difference if you specify them here or not.

Actually every package implicitly requires rtl and a lot of packages require vcl. So in any case you have to deploy *rtl250.bpl* and in most cases also *vcl250.bpl* when you compile with runtime packages.

If you don't want to deploy those bpl files just don't compile with runtime packages.